# How to make a script change on other user and the script continue on the new user?

Tags: shell, scripting, sudo, eof

i am creating a script that create a user, mount a virtual partition (an .img like partition), now on the structure of the code, i need to login to the new user and make so configuration for the user, so i was looking and found a close solution but with some errors.

This is the Code:

```
sudo -u lfs -s << "EOF"
cat > ~/.bashrc << "EOF"
set +h
umask 022
LFS=/mnt/lfs
LC_ALL=POSIX
LFS_TGT=$(uname -m)-lfs-linux-gnu
PATH=/tools/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
export LFS LC_ALL LFS_TGT PATH
export MAKEFLAGS='-j 20' 
EOF
```

The error i am getting is:

```
/bin/bash: line 9: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

if i add other EOF it's taked like a command or a string and depend on how i put it, will go into the .bashrc of the user.

so, i wanna know, how can i use EOF into EOF and close the EOFs?

thank you.

Comment: Don't use `EOF` for both. Use `EOF1` / `EOF2` or something. And you should probably read up on the difference between `<< "EOF"` and `<< 'EOF'`.

Comment: Also, if you are doing `> ~/.bashrc`, you can do `cp bashrc.proto ~lfs/.bashrc; chown lfs ~lfs/.bashrc` and maybe also `chmod`. If your system has `install` then you can do cp/chown/chmod all in one step

Comment: @jhnc thank you for the answer, now i dont found difference on "EOF" and 'EOF', i run the code and is the same.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking about Perl, where `"EOF"` behaves like `EOF`.